# How to fix this mesh issue?

Tags: mesh, vertices, faces, edges

I created an arm, and then a hand separated for it. The arm have less vertices and edges then the hand, so to connect them I had to do like this

[image]

[image]

The problem is those things in the mesh, because one vertice has a lot of edges connected to it.

[image]

Is there a way to make the hand and the arm to be more uniform, to make those things dissapear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sanbaldo says, use trick to keep good topology, meaning quads as much as possible, see this site for example: https://topologyguides.com/

Here are examples of edge loops reductions:

[image]

[image]

For your hand you could try the following method, first delete vertices:

[image]

Then draw this topology:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you need to study how to connect different shapes, having a good quad topology preserved:

[image]

[image]